# How are these products programatically replying to App Store reviews, and how can I do the same?

Tags: ios, api, app-store-connect, review

I've noticed a few products in the field (e.g. [here](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-london-54564448) and [here](https://docs.appfigures.com/api/reference/v2/reviews)) that are offering an API to programatically reply to App Store reviews, i.e. including iOS App Store.

My research suggests that the App Store Connect API does not expose this functionality, so can anybody explain how I am able to achieve the same functionality?

Is there, for example, an undocumented API I might use, or are these products little more than mechanical turks?